# issue formatting an array using printf (int, string, double, string, string)

Tags: java, arrays, printf

```
Array[] myArray = new Array[total];

for(int j = 0; j < total; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%25s", myArray[j]);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

I want 25 spaces in between each value but every I write this it doesnt change

Comment: What type is `Array`? Is it `java.lang.reflect.Array` or a different type?

Comment: its printing out an array of strings, doubles, int from a text file

Comment: That's not my question. My question is what is the **fully-qualified type name** of `Array` in this context?